# how can web/database servers access shared storage at the same time since it isn't possible?

Tags: filesystems, storage, sharing, san

having seen this post

[Can a SAN allow concurrent write access to the same file from several servers?](https://superuser.com/questions/241009/can-a-san-allow-concurrent-write-access-to-the-same-file-from-several-servers#new-answer?newreg=1bfd6ad25ef9461e803be0f9edc22dba)

I would like to ask how can web/database servers access shared storage at the same time since it isn't possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Shared storage would not be connected in the same way as dedicated storage. Both may be in the same SAN, but how the machines connect to them will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: the answer you quoted is (at least in most of its parts) wrong. Or, to put it differently: it is true only in a very specific set of circumstances.

Second: it's complicated.

There are different technologies how servers are connected to SAN storage. That means different (physical) means of connection and different protocols using these means of connections. I will not explain all these technologies and protocols in detail, because this would be a book rather than an answer. I will concentrate only on the most common things:

Typically one uses *Fibre Channel* to connect LUNs from the SAN to the hosts. Which host is allowed to connect (mount, ...) certain LUNs is declared via a process called "zoning". Picture zoning as similar to creating VLANs: each device has a unique number (in FC this is called "WWPN" and it works similar to a MAC-address in LANs) and a "zone" is basically a rule (in the FC-Switch) saying that a list of certain WWPNs are allowed to communicate with each other. Since each FC-adapter and each LUN are equally assigned such a WWPN you can state that a certain FC-adapter (hence - system, host) is allowed to use a certain disk (LUN).

It is entirely possible to have several hosts connect to the same LUN and hence "see" the same disk. In high-availability-clusters (like, i.e. IBM PowerHA) this is the normal way of operation: all *nodes* (member hosts of a cluster) see the disks, one mounts the filesystems on them and if it crashes, the next node takes over, mounts the now abandoned disks, etc..

It is also possible that many nodes access the disks even in Read/Write. This is the way i.e. Oracle RAC-Clusters work. Notice, though, that the underlying technology doesn't provide safeguards for this: this is the responsibility of the drivers, either the FC-(MPIO-)drivers or the filesystem drivers using them. An example would be IBMs GPFS.